# why am i getting the error GTK_container is not declared

Tags: c, gtk

I'm trying to make this function to be called by a button event but it keeps saying GTK_container is not declared in this scope

```
int record(void)
{
    GtkWidget *window, *button1, *gpointer;
    gtk_container_remove(GTK_WINDOW(window), button1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiler does not understand type of the second argument of

```
  void record(gtkWidget *window, *button1)
```

it must be

```
  void record(gtkWidget *window, gtkWidget *button1)
```

if `button1` is of the same type as `window` (is it also `gtkWidget *`?).

And local variables, declared as

```
  gtkWidget *window, *button1;
```

should be removed or renamed in order to not hide the scope of function's arguments

**EDIT:**

After you changed your function to

```
int record(void)
```

Pay attention at return value of your function. Where is the `return` with `int` value?

Comment: thanks, it's now saying gtk_container is not declared in this scope i'm not sure why as this is the first time this has happened

Comment: if you do not receive the values as arguments values of `window` and `button1` are not initialized before coaling `gtk_container_remove` - is it OK? - I do not think so...  And how is the `gpointer` used in the function?

Comment: not sure why gpointer is as I'm not using it and if I don't initialize them I get the error for them as well

Comment: The real type is `GtkWidget`, not `gtkWidget`.

Answer (score -1):

**Point 1.** `(gtkWidget *window, *button1)` as parameter list should read `(gtkWidget *window, gtkWidget  *button1)`. You were missing the type for the second variable.

**Point 2.** What is the purpose of defining those two variables once again locally inside in your function? That's not required, IMO.

---

EDIT:

As you've changed your function definition to return an `int`, you've to add a `return <some integer value>` statement, too. Otherwise, if the return value of this function is used that will invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

From the `C11` standard document, chapter 6.9.1, paragraph 12,

> If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by
>   the caller, the behavior is undefined.